# Cakephp table name convention

Tags: php, cakephp, naming-conventions

I have an existing site in `Joomla`. and I want new application in `CakePHP` but with same existing Joomla site database.

So here is the problem with the tables name. Please suggest me how to use that table (like `market_type`, `listing_type` in singular form) in `Cakephp`, because in `cakephp` standard we use tables in plural form.

Answer (score 9):

You can define table name in model

```
class Example extends AppModel {
public $useTable = 'exmp'; // This model uses a database table 'exmp'
}
```

[Use Table Cakephp](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usetable)

Comment: Yes this is a good answer, you will also likely have to define the primary and foreign keys as I doubt they will be in the same format as cakephp requires

Answer (score 2):

You could also add custom rules to the inflector. This way the baker will understood your table names, too.

```
// somewhere in your bootstrap.php
Inflector::rules('plural', array('irregular' => array('singular' => 'plural')));
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also always use Inflector's methods classify() and tableize() to find out what Cake would expect as a table names/model names for a given model. A simple reverse-engineering of your example shall explain this:

```
    $model = Inflector::classify('market_type');
```

which would give you

```
    MarketType
```

as the expected model name.

The table name therefore is:

```
    Inflector::tableize('MarketType');
```

which gives

```
    market_types
```

for the first mentioned table in your scenario.

The Inflector-class has many useful methods when working with strings in CakePHP, see the documentation here:
[CakePHP 2.x: Inflector](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/inflector.html)

These are in fact the correct names by Cake's conventions, and I would highly recommend sticking to that when using the framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your any table with using the model(in which you want to use that table) :

### ***public $useTable = 'tablename';***

But in cakePhp table name convention is plural of model name to make a relation implicitely..